# Only one cell could get user input - TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have three cells in my tableview which is standard tableview not custom cell. However, I would like the last cell to be editable, in other words I want that cell to get user input, something like textfield, but other cells just static and not editable.

I know how to make custom cell and make it work, but before I dive into that option I would like to know is there a tweak that I could use.

I wonder it is possible without making all tableview in custom cell?

Comment: No it is not possible without custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITableViewHeaderFooterView instead of last cell. I think it is better way to add some UI into TableView.

You just need to override a method which is here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006942-CH3-SW22

There is a simple example here: 
http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-headers-footers-table-view-ios7

I hope that is helpful for you.